# pyqt5 - items in QHBoxLayout overlap?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I've seen several similar questions on items overlapping in (py)Qt, but I cannot for the life of me figure out why I get these overlapping elements (label and slider) inside a `QHBoxLayout`:

[image: pyqt5-overlap.png]

... with this code:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class Example(QWidget):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Example, self).__init__()

    self.initUI()

  @pyqtSlot()
  def onclick(self):
    print("AAA")
    # QApplication.processEvents()
    setstr = ""
    if self.btn_yrange.isChecked(): setstr = "yrange auto ON"
    else: setstr = "yrange auto OFF"
    self.btn_yrange.setText(setstr)
    #self.btn_yrange.adjustSize()

  def initUI(self):
    self.col = QColor(0, 0, 0)

    self.slider_hbox = QHBoxLayout()

    self.btn_yrange = QPushButton('yrange auto OFF', self)
    self.btn_yrange.setCheckable(True)
    self.btn_yrange.clicked.connect(self.onclick)

    self.slider_yrange = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
    self.slider_yrange.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
    self.slider_yrange.setTickPosition(QSlider.TicksBothSides)
    self.slider_yrange.setTickInterval(10)
    self.slider_yrange.setSingleStep(1)

    self.slider_hbox.addStretch(1)
    self.slider_hbox.addWidget(self.btn_yrange, Qt.AlignRight)
    self.slider_hbox.addStretch(1)
    self.slider_hbox.addSpacing(10)
    self.slider_hbox.addWidget(self.slider_yrange)
    self.slider_hbox.addStretch(1)

    self.setGeometry(300, 300, 280, 170)
    self.setWindowTitle('Toggle button')
    self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  ex = Example()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

How do I force the label and the slider to be side-by-side?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it - I saw http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/layout/ - and realized, I had forgotten to add `self.setLayout(self.slider_hbox)` before `self.setGeometry`. So, now I get this:

[image: pyqt5-hbox-ok.png]

... with this code:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class Example(QWidget):
  def __init__(self):
    super(Example, self).__init__()

    self.initUI()

  @pyqtSlot()
  def onclick(self):
    print("AAA")
    # QApplication.processEvents()
    setstr = ""
    if self.btn_yrange.isChecked(): setstr = "yrange auto ON"
    else: setstr = "yrange auto OFF"
    self.btn_yrange.setText(setstr)
    #self.btn_yrange.adjustSize()

  def initUI(self):
    self.col = QColor(0, 0, 0)

    self.slider_hbox = QHBoxLayout()

    self.btn_yrange = QPushButton('yrange auto OFF', self)
    self.btn_yrange.setCheckable(True)
    #btn_yrange.move(10, 10)
    #self.btn_yrange.clicked.connect(self.onclick)
    self.btn_yrange.clicked.connect(self.onclick)

    self.slider_yrange = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal, self)
    self.slider_yrange.setFocusPolicy(Qt.StrongFocus)
    self.slider_yrange.setTickPosition(QSlider.TicksBothSides)
    self.slider_yrange.setTickInterval(10)
    self.slider_yrange.setSingleStep(1)

    #self.slider_hbox.addStretch(1)
    self.slider_hbox.addWidget(self.btn_yrange, Qt.AlignRight)
    #self.slider_hbox.addStretch(1)
    self.slider_hbox.addSpacing(10)
    self.slider_hbox.addWidget(self.slider_yrange)
    #self.slider_hbox.addStretch(1)

    self.setLayout(self.slider_hbox)

    self.setGeometry(300, 300, 280, 170)
    self.setWindowTitle('Toggle button')
    self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  ex = Example()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```